# Refreshing @Html.ListBox content with results from ajax call in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have two `@Html.ListBox` in my view:

```
IEnumerable<Models.CategoryModel> categories = ViewBag.AllCategories;
IEnumerable<Models.TypeModel> types = ViewBag.AllTypes;

@Html.Label("Category", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.ListBox("CategoriesFilter", new MultiSelectList(categories, "CatID", "Category"), new { @class = "chosen-select" })
</div>

 @Html.Label("Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.ListBox("TypesFilter", new MultiSelectList(types, "TID", "Description"), new { @class = "chosen-select" })
 </div>
```

When the user selects/deselects a category, I need to refresh the types in `@Html.ListBox("TypesFilter")`. I am doing an ajax call as follows:

```
$("#CategoriesFilter").change(function () {
    setTypesByCategory();
});

function setTypesByCategory() {
    var categoryIDs = ($('#CategoriesFilter').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("SetTypesByCategory", "Issues"))",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{ "categoryIDs" : "' + categoryIDs + '" }',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                    window.alert("success !!!" + k + " test " + this.STID);
                });
            });

            $("#TypesFilter").empty();
            $("#TypesFilter").val(data.TypesData);
        }              
    });
}
```

And in my controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public JsonResult SetTypesByCategory(string categoryIDs)
{
    string[] categories = categoryIDs.Split(',');
    List<TypeModel> filterdTypesList = new List<TypeModel>();
    foreach (var catID in categories)
    {
        foreach (var type in types.Where(m => m.CatID == Int32.Parse(catID)))
        {
            filterdTypesList.Add(type);
        }
    }
    int modelCount = filterdTypesList.Count();
    IEnumerable<TypeModel> filterdTypes = filterdTypesList;

    return Json(new { TypesData = filterdTypes, ModelCount = modelCount });
}
```

First, the types list box is not being empty when using `$("#TypesFilter").empty();`. And how can i populate this listbox with the obtained results?

Comment: You appear to be using the chosen select plugin? If so, use the methods provided by the plugin to update the options.

Comment: Probably this may work to remove all option items from listbox: `$("#TypesFilter option").each(function () { $(this).remove(); });`. With same jQuery.each function you can create option tags with provided value, or use `ListBoxFor` with `SelectListItem` to bind your listbox.